# Map a collection using Mapstruct and specify method for a single instance?

Tags: collections, mapstruct

i have a mapstruct class with the following functions

```
    abstract CustomApplication convertCustomApplication(ApplicationDTO source);

    abstract RegularApplication convertRegularApplication(ApplicationDTO source);

    @Named("mainConverter")
    public App mainConverter(ApplicationDTO source) {
        return source.isCustom() ? convertCustomApplication(source) : convertRegularApplication(source);
    }

    //@Mapping( qualifiedByName = "mainConverter")
    abstract public List<App> convertApplications(List<ApplicationDTO> applicationList);
```

Both CustomApplication and RegularApplication extend App, so I have mainConverter that calls the converter according to the isCustom field.

The problem is that when i try to build this i get an ambiguous mapping error, because mainConverter, convertRegularApplication, and convertCustomApplication all map from ApplicationDTO to App (or subclass of App). So convertApplications does not know what to use.
Is there any way i can explicitly tell it to call mainConverter? I wanted something like @Mapping( qualifiedByName = "mainConverter") that I put above convertApplications, (but it doesnt work of course)
Does anyone know how I can do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you are looking for you will need to use [`IterableMapping#qualifiedByName`](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/IterableMapping.html#qualifiedByName--).

This property is meant to enhance the selection for the list.

e.g.

```
    abstract CustomApplication convertCustomApplication(ApplicationDTO source);

    abstract RegularApplication convertRegularApplication(ApplicationDTO source);

    @Named("mainConverter")
    public App mainConverter(ApplicationDTO source) {
        return source.isCustom() ? convertCustomApplication(source) : convertRegularApplication(source);
    }

    @IterableMapping(qualifiedByName = "mainConverter")
    abstract public List<App> convertApplications(List<ApplicationDTO> applicationList);
```

## Alternative solution

You are making your `mainConverter` qualified method. However, it looks like that method already redirects to the more specific method. Therefore I would suggest to qualify the other two methods and remove the qualification from the `mainConverter`. Then you won't need to do anything for the iterable mapping.

e.g.

```
    @Named("customApplication")
    abstract CustomApplication convertCustomApplication(ApplicationDTO source);

    @Named("regularApplication")
    abstract RegularApplication convertRegularApplication(ApplicationDTO source);

    public App mainConverter(ApplicationDTO source) {
        return source.isCustom() ? convertCustomApplication(source) : convertRegularApplication(source);
    }

    abstract public List<App> convertApplications(List<ApplicationDTO> applicationList);
```